# How can i connect ethernet connected camera through python (Flir AX8 camera)

Tags: python, camera, ethernet

I am trying to connect a Flir AX8 camera through python. This camera is connected to the ethernet port of the laptop. So, the `VideoCapture()` isn't recognising the port, I've tried all indexes for it (0, 1, 2), but it doesn't connect. Can anyone help me that how can i connect the camera to python?

I have tried connecting through `VideoCapture(1)` and through `VideoCapture('IP address')`

#### Using the IP address:

```
import cv2, time
video=cv2.VideoCapture('http://admin:admin@IP address/')

a=0

while True:
    a=a+1
    check, frame = video.read()

    print(check)
    print(frame)

    #gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)

    key=cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key== ord('q'):
        break

print(a)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

#### Using the index 0, 1, 2:

```
import cv2, time
video=cv2.VideoCapture(1)

a=0

while True:
    a=a+1
    check, frame = video.read()

    print(check)
    print(frame)

    #gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)

    key=cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key== ord('q'):
        break

print(a)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I am getting following error in both situations:

```
False
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yashw\Desktop\ex.py", line 15, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: So what protocol is used for sending data? And are you trying to just save the screenshot of a video stream from your camera? Are you actively trying to control the camera trough its API

Comment: I am using this camera for finding the location of an object. This camera is connected by FLIR IP CONFIG. software.

Comment: Did you read its instructions on how to [configure the server?](https://www.flir.eu/support-center/Instruments/how-do-i-configure-an-ftp-server-on-my-pc-to-work-with-the-flir-ax8-or-a310/)

Comment: Yes, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import cv2
import numpy as np

while True:
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture('http://admin:admin@169.254.253.219/snapshot.jpg?user=admin&pwd=admin&strm=0')
    ret,img=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('videos output',img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(1) 
    if k==ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows